Macro to automatically update dates in Excel spreadsheet formulas and conditional formatting?
I have an Excel 365 spreadsheet that gets re-created each year. It contains a lot of formulas containing dates (full year or date ranges for calendar quarters) and conditional formatting (with formulas that contain dates). Can I create a macro that prompts the user to enter a year and then updates all cell formulas and conditional formatting formulas across all sheets in a workbook?
Currently, I do a standard search and replace for the cell formulas, but I have to manually update all the dates in the conditional formatting formulas. I anticipate passing this task to another person in the coming months, and I'd like to make this update process as simple/automatic as possible, since my successor will in all likelihood NOT have the advanced Excel skills or the time to do the manual updates, especially since this task is only done once a year.

I believe that Powershell has a function to edit Excel documents and should be able to do this, but is this not something you could do with a field in the document?
https://miajimyu.com/en/docs/powershell/powershell-tips/how-to-edit-excel/
https://woshub.com/read-write-excel-files-powershell/
Could you not change the date to reference a cell in a blank part of the document, or to reference a cell on a different "configuration/date" sheet?

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Thanks. I'll try changing the date to a cell reference elsewhere in the file. Unfortunately, I can't use any application other than Excel, since my employer's IT systems are locked down pretty tight to preserve security.
